# Font size CSS problem in IE

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

```
<span style="font-size: 11pt;"> some text in "malayalam" language </span>
```

I am using the above code to control the font size of a particular part in a text. The font size worked perfectly in chrome and Firefox, but not in ie8, what to do ? I am new to CSS , plz help. I am using unicode to reneder my "Malayalam" font

Comment: Can you show screen shots or explain otherwise what didn't work? `font-size` is basic CSS 1 and no browser out there currently in use gets that wrong. Do you have conflicting rules maybe? Do other browsers have different font size defaults so you don't see the result? Have you checked in the developer tools? Is your page parsed in Standards Mode in IE?

Comment: How exactly did it not work in ie8?

Comment: look at the font below the heading "Latest Malayalam film news. All recent gossips from Malluwood" in moviesmalayalam.com . I will upload the screen shot in just a minute

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/31/unled1xm.jpg/

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/691/unled2cp.jpg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point (pt) sizes don't work reliably in browsers, I'd recommend pixels (px) or em's.

> A point is a unit of measurement used for real-life ink-on-paper
>   typography. 72pts = one inch. One inch = one real-life inch
>   like-on-a-ruler. Not an inch on a screen, which is totally arbitrary
>   based on resolution.

Via [CSS-Tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/2580-css-font-size/)

In more recent browser releases pixel support has become better and better, if you are working with Photoshop based designs you might find them easier than em's. If not, [pxtoem.com](http://pxtoem.com/) can help.

Comment: I converted the size to 16em. Now the font size is very small in Firefox, medium in chrome, and very large in IE

Comment: I am using unicde to render my "Malayalam" font. Is that has any connection with the font size problem

Comment: I can't find proof of your claim that point sizes don't work reliably on the linked site.

Answer (score -1):

try using 11px or whatever you want size you want, but in pixels - so not "pt" but "px". It's more fixed.

Comment: Points are well-defined in CSS, too. Just read the specification.